# how to create list and sublist -android?

Tags: android

I am new to android.Can any one help me .how to create a list.
example:
List1
by selecting list1
I should get list1 items in sublist list1.1,list1.2....
List2
by selecting list2
sublist items as
list2.1
list2.2

Please help me.

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), which allows you to have two levels of expansion. Listview (which is what is used in the NotePad example) only allows one level.

I haven't started working with those yet, so I can't recommend any specific tutorials or examples, but now that you know the name of what you are looking for, poke around the android dev site and google about. The first search hit is [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html) if it's worth anything.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would spend some time going through the sample code and references on d.android.com

Have a look at ListView and the Notepad example project
http://d.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html